# Search Nested JSON with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, treeview

I have a large Nested JSON file which I use to bind to a treeview. I want to search this treeview datasource by text and get all the nodes that match up until its parent so I can preserve tree structure. So lets say I have a JSON like below:

```js
[
  {
    "x": "Root-1",
    "y": "000001",
    "c": [
      {
        "x": "child-1",
        "y": "000001.1"
      },
      {
        "x": "child-2",
        "y": "000001.2",
        "c": [
          {
            "x": "child-3",
            "y": "000001.3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "x": "Root-2",
    "y": "000002",
    "c": [
      {
        "x": "child-4",
        "y": "000002.1"
      },
      {
        "x": "child-5",
        "y": "000002.2",
        "c": [
          {
            "x": "child-6",
            "y": "000002.3",
            "c": [
              {
                "x": "child-7",
                "y": "000002.4"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now in a textbox, I want to do a contains search for: "1.3" and it should return me below objects with same nesting:

child-3(since this matched), child-2(child-3's parent) and root-1(child-2's parent).

Now I can use this JSON to bind to my tree-view.

Comment: the old and evil question: what have you tried, show us some code

Comment: please add an example of the wanted return value.

Comment: the easy way: JSON.stringify each array element as you iterate, then match your term to the JSON. `r.filter(x=>JSON.stringify(x).match(term))`

Answer (score 1):

Actually unlike arbitrary text strings, once stringified, the JSON data yields a pretty regularly structured string hence we may apply cool regular expressions which diminish the code into a 2~3 liner. I am not sure whether this one or the recursive or iterative one is more efficient. I'll give it a try later.

TL&DR The code is this. F12 is your friend.

```
function regExpEscape(literal_string) {
  return literal_string.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?.\/\\^$|#\s,]/g, '\\$&');
}
// assuming that your json data is assigned to a variable jd
var js = JSON.stringify(jd),
    sd = 1.3.toString(), //this input value should be supplied as string
   rx1 = new RegExp('{"x":"([\\w-]+)[",:\\w]+(?=' + regExpEscape(sd) + ')',"g"),
   rar = [],
result = [];

rar = rx1.exec(js); // < ["{"x":"child-3","y":"00000", "child-3"]
rar.length && result.push(rar[1]); // if rar is not empty save rar[1] to result 
var rx2 = new RegExp('{"x":"([\\w-]+)(?=[":,\\.\\w-]+\\[{[\\[{}":,\\.\\w-]+'  + regExpEscape(result[0]) + ')',"g");
while (!!(rar = rx2.exec(js))){result.push(rar[1])} // ["child-3", "Root-1", "child-2"]
```

The story telling part:

Just in two steps we can get the result we are after. Lets see

In order to check if 1.3 exists and get the x property's value (name) we can use `/{"x":"([\w-]+)[",:\w]+(?=1\.3)/g` regexp. But then let's find a way to make this regex reusable.

```
// assuming that your search data is assigned to a variable sd
function regExpEscape(literal_string) {
  return literal_string.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?.\/\\^$|#\s,]/g, '\\$&');
}
var rx = '/{"x":"([\w-]+)[",:\w]+(?=' + regExpEscape(sd) + ')/g');
```

Ok now we have our regexp for any given search data. Let's carry on from where we have left...

```
// assuming that your json data is assigned to a variable jd
var js = JSON.stringify(jd),
    sd = 1.3.toString(), //this input value should be supplied as string
   rx1 = new RegExp('{"x":"([\\w-]+)[",:\\w]+(?=' + regExpEscape(sd) + ')',"g"),
   rar = [],
result = [];

rar = rx1.exec(js); // < ["{"x":"child-3","y":"00000", "child-3"]
rar.length && result.push(rar[1]); // if rar is not empty save rar[1] to result
```

So far so good. We have the name of the object with the result that we were searching for. Now in order to get the same info from it's parents we will use these two facts

1. Between the child and it's parent there shouldn't be any `]` character.
2. The parent element is reached when met the `[` character.

Cool lets carry on. I had a little bit of brain melted over this and came up with the `/{"x":"([\w-]+)(?=[":,\.\w-]+\[{[\[{}":,\.\w-]+child-3)/g` Well ok it looks somewhat cryptic but actually quite simple. Let me go through. It's composed of two parts xxx(yyy) must precede (?= [allowed characters] followed by [{ then [some more allowed characters] followed by "child-3".) Since we never allow the `]` character we will never get to anybodies child but only parents and siblings. We don't want siblings.. accordingly we have `\[{` So that's how we get to the parent and bypass the siblings. We've got the wanted chain.

Lets finish it;

```
var rx2 = new RegExp('{"x":"([\\w-]+)(?=[":,\\.\\w-]+\\[{[\\[{}":,\\.\\w-]+'  + regExpEscape(result[0]) + ')',"g");
while (!!(rar = rx2.exec(js))){result.push(rar[1])}
```

this seems to be it. Regardless how deep is your JSON object gets.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone. We have the same JSON data stored in an SQL table with parent ids and other info. We actually went with using an existing SQL stored proc that searches the data in database and returns the records as relational data. We than use C# code to convert this relational data into JSON string and use it to show search results.

Answer (score 0):

This proposal iterates over a possible array and builds for every level an array with its predecessor nodes and if `search` is found, the path is pushed to the result. The iteration works with short-circuit. For the next level, the function is called again with a new base and the former path to the actual node.

```js
function getNodes(tree, search) {
    function n(a, t) {
        return Array.isArray(a) && a.some(function (b) {
            return b.y.match(search) && r.push([].concat(b, t)) || n(b.c, [].concat(b, t));
        });
    }

    var r = [];
    n(tree, []);
    return r;
}

var tree = [{ "x": "Root-1", "y": "000001", "c": [{ "x": "child-1", "y": "000001.1" }, { "x": "child-2", "y": "000001.2", "c": [{ "x": "child-3", "y": "000001.3" }] }] }, { "x": "Root-2", "y": "000002", "c": [{ "x": "child-4", "y": "000002.1" }, { "x": "child-5", "y": "000002.2", "c": [{ "x": "child-6", "y": "000002.3", "c": [{ "x": "child-7", "y": "000002.4" }] }] }] }];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getNodes(tree, '1.3'), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these recursive functions:

```
var result = find( data, 1, 1, 0, 0 );

function find() {
    var args = [].slice.call( arguments );
    var root = args.shift();
    if( args.length == 0 ) return [];
    var index = args.shift();
    root = nthChild( root, index );
    if( typeof root  === 'undefined' ) {
        throw Error( "Invalid index " + index + " at level " + args.length + " from the tail!" );
    }
    args.unshift( root );
    return [root].concat( find.apply( undefined, args ) );
}


function nthChild( root, index ) {
    // If we are not in an array, let take the "c" attribute.
    if( !Array.isArray( root ) ) root = root.c;
    return root[index];
}
```